# sublime capture event before closing window

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext

I'm trying to capture the event when closing a sublime window. I have been trying to use the `plugin_unloaded` but this method doesn't seem to be called when closing the window

```
def plugin_unloaded():
    with open('/home/user/aaaaaa.txt', 'w') as fp:
        fp.write("test\n")
```

I expect the file to be created when closing the window but it ain't, so is there a method that is triggered and I can use to perform some actions when the window is closed?

Answer (score 1):

Plugins in Sublime are essentially global in that they are only loaded once (generally, see below). As such there isn't a new copy loaded for each window that is created.

In particular, Sublime loads plugins:

- When it initially starts
- When they first appear inside of a package (for newly added plugins)
- When the source file that they're in is changed on disk
- When the package that they're stored in is removed from the `ignored_packages` setting, making the package active once again.

Similarly, plugins are only unloaded:

- When Sublime is about to re-load it because it changed on disk
- When the package that they're stored in is added to the `ignored_packages` setting, making the package no longer active

That said, there is no foolproof way to detect when a window is actually closed, although depending on the reason you want to know that the window is being closed, there may be a work-around that works "good enough".

One method is to use an `EventListener` to detect when the `close_window` command is either just about to be executed or has just finished executing.

Problems with this method are that the command doesn't get executed if you use the window chrome to close the window, so you can only detect the window closing this way if the user uses the key binding or menu entry to close the window.

Also the command is always fully executed even if the window doesn't actually close (i.e. if there is an unsaved file and you cancel) and it finishes executing while the window still exists, requiring you to wait a little bit before checking to see if the window still exists or not:

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class WindowCloseListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def check_closed(self, w_id):
        for window in sublime.windows():
            if window.id() == w_id:
                return print("Window %d cancelled close" % w_id)

        print("Window %d has closed" % w_id)

    def on_window_command(self, window, cmd, args):
        if cmd == "close_window":
            print("window with id %d is about to close" % window.id())

    def on_post_window_command(self, window, cmd, args):
        if cmd == "close_window":
            sublime.set_timeout(lambda: self.check_closed(window.id()), 250)
```

Another method is to keep polling and seeing if the list of windows is changing in a way that a window that used to exist is going away. However doing that sort of check is going to cost some performance, which may or may not be acceptable.

Possibly you can trade off the poll time (below it's 5 seconds) for less of a performance hit if you don't need to know right away that a window is closing.

However, with a larger interval the chances that someone can create a new window and close it without you never knowing it existed go up (although in theory you could also catch the `new_window` command to try and mitigate that).

It also won't tell you when the last window closes because there is no way to determine when Sublime is quitting.

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import random

random.seed()
g_sentinel = random.random()

def check(sentinel, old_w):
    new_w = {w.id() for w in sublime.windows()}
    closed = old_w - new_w
    if closed:
        print("Windows closed: %s" % closed)

    if sentinel == g_sentinel:
        sublime.set_timeout_async(lambda: check(sentinel, new_w), 5000)

def plugin_loaded():
    w_list = {w.id() for w in sublime.windows()}
    sublime.set_timeout_async(lambda: check(g_sentinel, w_list), 5000)

def plugin_unloaded():
    global g_sentinel
    g_sentinel = 0
```

This polls every five seconds by using `set_timeout_async` to call a method that calls itself with another time out. In order to be safe it also uses a global sentinel value so that a running poll can detect when the plugin has been reloaded or unloaded entirely and stop itself.

Without such a check you'll quickly have several polls going if plugin reloads are happening, such as when you're actively working on your plugin.